# Class method in javascript is not a function

Tags: javascript, class, object

The answer must be obvious but I don't see it

here is my javascript class :

```
var Authentification = function() {
        this.jeton = "",
        this.componentAvailable = false,
        Authentification.ACCESS_MASTER = "http://localhost:1923",

        isComponentAvailable = function() {
            var alea = 100000*(Math.random());

            $.ajax({
               url:  Authentification.ACCESS_MASTER + "/testcomposant?" + alea,
               type: "POST",
               success: function(data) {
                   echo(data);
               },
               error: function(message, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(status);
                    alert(errorThrown);
               }
            });
            
            return true;
        };
    };
```

then I instanciate

```
var auth = new Authentification();

alert(Authentification.ACCESS_MASTER);    
alert(auth.componentAvailable);
alert(auth.isComponentAvailable());
```

I can reach everything but the last method, it says in firebug :

> auth.isComponentAvailable is not a function

.. but it is..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`isComponentAvailable` isn't attached to (ie is not a property of) your object, it is just enclosed by your function; which makes it private.

You could prefix it with `this` to make it pulbic

`this.isComponentAvailable = function() {`

Answer (score 4):

isComponentAvailable  is actually attached to the window object.

Comment: True, but you should have posted as a comment- not an answer

Answer (score 2):

`isComponentAvailable` is a private function. You need to make it public by adding it to `this` like so:

```
var Authentification = function() {
    this.jeton = "",
    this.componentAvailable = false,
    Authentification.ACCESS_MASTER = "http://localhost:1923";

    this.isComponentAvailable = function() {
        ...
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is:

```
var Authentification = function() {
    // class data
    // ...
};

Authentification.prototype = {    // json object containing methods
    isComponentAvailable: function(){
        // returns a value
    }
};

var auth = new Authentification();
alert(auth.isComponentAvailable());
```